# Possibility of converting an Non-REST ASP.NET site to REST architecture

Tags: asp.net, rest

I'm just wondering it is possible to convert a Non-REST ASP.NET website to REST architecure? If so, how to do it?

(The site actually have DAL and Business Logic Layer helper classes).

Comment: What benefits are you trying to gain?  If we know what you are trying to achieve then we may be able to point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, REST means different things to different people so you need to define what exactly you mean by REST. Is it only clean URLs? Does it include using alternative HTTP methods such as PUT and DELETE? Does it include custom verbs? Will it have meta tags informing the client how to interact with a document?

It very much depend on how the website has been implemented. But this will require a lot of manual conversion.

Best is you put a snippet out and ask people to change that snippet to REST.